# First option in dropdown disables submit button on form

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, forms, mailchimp

I have a form on my site that is hooked up to Mailchimp. It all seems to work perfectly apart from if the top option (currently 'all') is selected from the dropdown menu.

Here is the code for the form:

```
    <?php if(is_front_page()) { ?>

<style>
.fixed_header.social_header #main{padding-top: 0px!important;}
.mailchimp{ width: 100%;background: url(<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/images/bg_mc.png) no-repeat; background-position: left top; background-size: 100% 100% ; min-height: 399px; padding: 154px 0 20px 0;}
.inner-mailchimp{margin: 0 auto; width: 805px; text-align: center;}
.mailchimp h1, .mailchimp h3{color: #fff;} 
/*#news_mc, #everything, #business_mc, #technology_mc, #dnd_mc, #smedia_mc{display: none;}*/
#mc_embed_signup{background: none!important;}
#everything_mc{ display: block;}
.form_mc{width: 400px; float: left;}
#mc_embed_signup .mc-field-group select{ padding: 7px 0!important;}
#dnd_mc, #news_mc, #business_mc, #technology_mc, #smedia_mc{display:none;}
.mc-field-group label{color: #fff;}
#mc-embedded-subscribe-form .clear{visibility: visible; overflow: visible; right: -271px;  top: -13px; background: url(<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/images/c.png ); position: relative;}
#mc_embed_signup .button{ background-color: #005CBF!important; font-weight: normal!important;}

</style>
<script>

function fill_email(my_mail){
    var fillupemail = document.getElementById(my_mail).value;
    //alert(fillupemail);
    document.getElementById('unique_news').value = fillupemail;
    document.getElementById('unique_business').value = fillupemail;
    document.getElementById('unique_dnd').value = fillupemail;
    document.getElementById('unique_everything').value = fillupemail;
    document.getElementById('unique_smedia').value = fillupemail;
    document.getElementById('unique_technology').value = fillupemail;

}

function mailchange(id){
    var x = document.getElementById(id);

    if(x.value == 'everything'){
        document.getElementById('dnd_mc').style.display='none';
        document.getElementById('news_mc').style.display='none';
        document.getElementById('business_mc').style.display='none';
        document.getElementById('technology_mc').style.display='none';
        document.getElementById('smedia_mc').style.display='none';

        document.getElementById(x.value+'_mc').style.display='block';
    }
    if(x.value == 'news'){
        document.getElementById('everything_mc').style.display='none';
        document.getElementById('dnd_mc').style.display='none';
        document.getElementById('business_mc').style.display='none';
        document.getElementById('technology_mc').style.display='none';
        document.getElementById('smedia_mc').style.display='none';

        document.getElementById(x.value+'_mc').style.display='block';
    }
    if(x.value == 'business'){
        document.getElementById('everything_mc').style.display='none';
        document.getElementById('dnd_mc').style.display='none';
        document.getElementById('news_mc').style.display='none';
        document.getElementById('technology_mc').style.display='none';
        document.getElementById('smedia_mc').style.display='none';

        document.getElementById(x.value+'_mc').style.display='block';
    }
    if(x.value == 'technology'){
        document.getElementById('everything_mc').style.display='none';
        document.getElementById('dnd_mc').style.display='none';
        document.getElementById('news_mc').style.display='none';
        document.getElementById('business_mc').style.display='none';
        document.getElementById('smedia_mc').style.display='none';

        document.getElementById(x.value+'_mc').style.display='block';
    }
    if(x.value == 'dnd'){
        document.getElementById('everything_mc').style.display='none';
        document.getElementById('news_mc').style.display='none';
        document.getElementById('business_mc').style.display='none';
        document.getElementById('technology_mc').style.display='none';
        document.getElementById('smedia_mc').style.display='none';

        document.getElementById(x.value+'_mc').style.display='block';
    }
    if(x.value == 'smedia'){
        document.getElementById('everything_mc').style.display='none';
        document.getElementById('dnd_mc').style.display='none';
        document.getElementById('news_mc').style.display='none';
        document.getElementById('business_mc').style.display='none';
        document.getElementById('technology_mc').style.display='none';

        document.getElementById(x.value+'_mc').style.display='block';
    }

}
</script>

<div class="mailchimp">
    <div class="inner-mailchimp">
        <h1>Scientia potentia est</h1>
        <h3>Knowledge is Power</h3>
        <div class="form_mc">
            <?php include('mailchimp-everything.php'); ?>
            <?php include('mailchimp-news.php'); ?>
            <?php include('mailchimp-business.php'); ?>
            <?php include('mailchimp-technology.php'); ?>
            <?php include('mailchimp-dnd.php'); ?>
            <?php include('mailchimp-smedia.php'); ?>
        </div><!-- form -->
        <div class="form_mc">

            <div class="everything_mc display_mc" id="mc_embed_signup"><form>
            <div class="mc-field-group selectmail_mc">
                <label for="mce-EMAIL">Interest </label>
                <select onchange="mailchange(this.id)" id="selectmail_c">
                    <option value="everything">All</option>
                    <option value="news">News</option>
                    <option value="business">Business</option>
                    <option value="technology">Technology</option>
                    <option value="dnd">Design & Development</option>
                    <option value="smedia">Social Media</option>
                </select>
            </div></form>
            </div>

        </div><!-- form -->
        <small style="color: #FFFFFF; float: left; font-size: 13px; margin-bottom: 20px; text-align: center; width: 100%;">Don't worry there's no spam just intriguing posts and <u>free</u> resources.</small>
    </div>
</div>
 <?php } ?>
```

I have checked through the separate files for each selection on the drop-down too but they all seem correct so I believe the problem must be in this code. Unfortunely I can't understand it enough to decipher what the problem could be.

EDIT: [This is the site](http://rerral.com) and it is the form just below the header.

Any help is much appreciates, thanks!

Comment: Any other ideas Stack world?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that if you select a different option from the drop down and then go back to the first dropdown option it works? (Unfortunatly I cannot post comments due to my low rep) I have the feeling that the issue may be that your mailchange function is not called on page load so you have to actually 'select' the all option instead of defaulting to it.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply. I just tried selecting another and then reverting back to the 'all' option however it still doesn't work.

Comment: I am confused why there is apparently an 'everything' element instead of just showing all elements.  I've never worked with mailchimp or php unfortunatly, but why don't you try just setting the display to visible on all elements in the x.value == 'everything' block?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean. Like this?


`if(x.value == 'everything'){
        document.getElementById('dnd_mc').style.display='visible';
        document.getElementById('news_mc').style.display='visible';
        document.getElementById('business_mc').style.display='visible';
        document.getElementById('technology_mc').style.display='visible';
        document.getElementById('smedia_mc').style.display='visible';
        
        document.getElementById(x.value+'_mc').style.display='block';
    }`


If so that doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: O.K. thanks for the link, I looked at it for a while, I'm pretty sure the stuff I mentioned before is not anywhere near the issue.  The only other thing I could find (this is pretty over my head I'm afraid) is that in the news_mc <div> there is `<input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email unique_news" onchange="fill_email(this.id)" id="unique_news" />` and in the everything_mc <div> there is `<input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" onchange="fill_email(this.id)" id="unique_everything">` perhaps you need a "unique_everything" added to the class?